# "Compressing" code in ternary conditional operation to add prefix to value

Tags: php, optimization, prefix, conditional-operator, php-7.3

Out of curiosity... is there a way to write this kind of code in a single statement in the shortest (less php code characters and duplication) form possible? e.g. without repeating the `document` part both as string and as a variable.

```
if (empty($id)){
  $fileName = "document.pdf";
} else {
  $fileName = "document_$id.pdf"; // the "_" is important
}
```

If I drop the underscore I can use shorthand ternary operator:

```
$fileName = 'document'.(empty($id) ?: '').'.pdf';
```

How can I include the underscore in a ternary operation like the above?

*Maybe a "ternary with prefix concatenation if true" operator ...*

Comment: Might also consider renaming your default document in your filesystem to `document_.pdf`. That would remove this runtime check all together, which likely is the most performent of all solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a possible solution, but it still repeats the `$id` reference...

```
$fileName = 'document' . (!empty($id) ? '_' . $id : '') . '.pdf';
```

Comment: This is fine, and readable. `$fileName = implode('_', array_filter(['document', $id ?? null])) . '.pdf';` should work if you absolutely don't want to repeat anything, but it's quite unintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$fileName = rtrim('document' . '_' . $id, '_') . '.pdf';
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want to repeat `$id` this is the shortest form I managed to write

```
$fileName = str_replace('_.','.','document_'.($id?:'').'.').'pdf';
```

As for `empty()` don't worry [Elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) will do the same job.